# 2 apple devices sharing same apple id’s causing issues

Tags: iphone, apple-id

so my husband and i have two apple iphones (8 & xsmax) we share the same apple id to share contacts between the two devices. It used to work when we had a iphone 6&8 but then we upgraded to 8&8 and now 8&xsmax. Both upgrads caused an glitch. Our incoming phone calls show on both devices. Text messages do not. Just the calls (whether recent or missed) show up on both phones. 
Is there a way to display recent or missed on each phone that it was called and not share this on both devices?

Comment: This has been asked a few times here over the years. The usual answer is to stop sharing the same Apple ID. With Family Sharing you can share contacts (and calendar entries) while keeping individual ID's. Can you do this?

Comment: I believe there is a cost for the family sharing correct?

Comment: No, it's free. See [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) for more info.  I've been using it in my own family for years. I did buy extra storage space so my kids could keep their pictures and data for longer periods of time. Doing this will solve many, if not all, of the problems you see with sharing ID's.

Comment: I apprecite the the help. I did manage to get different ids. Does it sync the contacts?

Comment: Yes, it can if you setup it that way.  It would be best if you look at the Apple pages for setting up Family Sharing as well as how to use the different apps.